# EXCEL RIBBON Hide Individual Tabs

Tags: c#, excel, tabs, ribbon, visible

Looking for code to Hide Individual Ribbon tabs.  Not the entire ribbon.   Seeking how to get to the Ribbon Tab collection using C# so I can process the object collection and hide certain tabs while leaving others visible.

Comment: Have you tried any code by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a Variable in Globals, there you can access your group and set the visibility. Try something like

`Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.group1.Visible = false;`

to make certain groups invisible for example.

But with a bit of research you could have found that by yourself ;)

Comment: I have VSTO code and the ribbon returns the VSTO Tab only, not the entire Ribbontab collection.  I can hide the VSTO TAB, I am unable to hide the default tabs via C# code.

Comment: added code yo collect all containers and process them (disable), not an ideal soolution